# Getting the Article's Category in Liferay 5

Tags: java, liferay, article

I'm using Liferay 5 and I developed a portlet that lists some articles (using the `JournalArticle` class).  The problem is that I cannot get the article's category.

I know that it's possible with Liferay 6, but can I do this in version 5?

Comment: Out of interest, how do you do it on Liferay 6?

Answer (score 1):

Liferay 5.2:

```
String className = JournalArticle.class.getName();
long classPK = 12345l; // This is the id of your article
boolean folksonomy = false; // Use true for retrieving tags, false for retrieving categories
List<TagsEntry> categories = TagsEntryLocalServiceUtil.getEntries(className, classPK, false);
```

Liferay 6.0:

```
List<AssetCategory> categories = AssetCategoryLocalServiceUtil.getCategories(className, classPK);
```